# left join returnt duplicate data on right table and count returns wrong result

Tags: sql, count, left-join

I have two table: imports and orders: I have attached these respectively.
[image]
[image]
Which I want are:
 1. all data of import table group by product id.
 2. sum of pieces column of orders table for a product id.
 In my tables there are 3 rows in import table having product id 1 and two rows in orders table having product id 1 and pieces of these two rows are: 1,5.
So my expected result is: all rows of import table not repeated of same product_id and total pieces is 6. but I am getting 18 instead of 6. but for product id 2 I am getting pieces as 1. That means 6 is repeated for 3 times due to 3 rows in imports table having product_id = 1.

But how can I get my expected result? Here is my query:

```
SELECT `Import`.*, SUM(case when orders.status = "sold" THEN orders.pieces else 0 end) as total_sell FROM `amrajegeachi`.`imports` AS `Import` LEFT OUTER JOIN `orders` ON `Import`.`product_id` = `orders`.`product_id` WHERE 1 = 1 GROUP BY `Import`.`product_id`
```

and this is the result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Import] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 1
                    [product_id] => 1
                    [amount] => 50
                    [cost] => 8320
                    [paid] => 0
                    [comment] => transportation and others cost: 100  
                    [created] => 2015-06-22 12:09:20
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [total_sell] => 18
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Import] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [category_id] => 2
                    [product_id] => 2
                    [amount] => 15
                    [cost] => 3000
                    [paid] => 0
                    [comment] => 
                    [created] => 2015-06-22 12:10:36
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [total_sell] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

Any suggestion is appropriated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read your question too quickly and did not answer your question:

You say `1. all data of import table group by product id. 2. sum of pieces column of orders table for a product id.`

You are using 'SUM' which is an aggregate function.  When you use an aggregate function, any other columns must be in a `GROUP BY` clause to aggregate them, so if you have:

```
Col1 | Col2 
1    | CategoryA
2    | CategoryA
2    | CategoryB
```

If you do select `SUM(Col1), Col2` that's not valid, because SUM is an aggregate and Col2 is not.  You need to `GROUP BY Col2`:

`SELECT SUM(Col1), Col2 FROM table GROUP BY Col2`

This will give you:

```
3 | CategoryA
2 | CategoryB
```

Your issue is that you are selecting * from the imports table, which is causing your grouping to be wrong.  You need to do:

```
SELECT
  `Import`.product_id, 
  SUM(case when orders.status = "sold" THEN orders.pieces else 0 end) as total_sell

  FROM `amrajegeachi`.`imports` AS `Import` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `orders` ON `Import`.`product_id` = `orders`.`product_id` 
  WHERE 1 = 1 
  GROUP BY `Import`.product_id
```

This should group your SUM by product ID and give you the right results.

Comment: I did this but no luck :'(
SELECT `Import`.*, SUM(case when orders.status = "sold" THEN orders.pieces else 0 end) as total_sell FROM `amrajegeachi`.`imports` AS `Import` LEFT JOIN `orders` ON `Import`.`product_id` = `orders`.`product_id` GROUP BY `Import`.`product_id`

Comment: @abdus-sattar-bhuiyan Check it now, I edited my answer

Comment: Yes, it works. but it returns duplicate data of imports table. I want to get one value of same product_id in imports table. but it returns all

Comment: Please give me hints to achieve this issue @mikeb

Comment: @abdus-sattar-bhuiyan - Have a look now, I was grouping by id, which is unique and therefore does nothing.  The new query selects by produc_id and groups by the same.  That will do what you want.